# PostgreSQL select a fixed time intervals from a range of days defined in timestamp

Tags: postgresql

The time data in my database is stored using timestamp. I want to select a fixed time intervals from a range of days. For example, select the tuples that has timestamp that satisfies: its time is between 2pm and 3pm, and its date is between 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-31.

`SELECT * FROM data WHERE ????time???? ;`

In plain English select the data that are recorded between 2pm and 3pm for January.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE time_column BETWEEN date '2015-01-01' AND date '2015-01-31'
  AND extract( hour from time_column ) BETWEEN 14 AND 15 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It works. What if I need to do select 14:00:00 to 14:01:01?

Comment: Also, can I use `...AND extract( hour from time_column ) BETWEEN '2 PM' AND '3 PM';`?